# Help Making Handle

Tags: modeling, mesh

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQoXX.jpg

I've tried making this handle using a bezier curve but it doesn't come out rounded, it's flat. Is there a way to make this rounded rather than square?

Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHOTs.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quickly made version: begin with a cylinder (16 vertices for example), in *Object* mode give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and press *Shading* > *Smooth* in the *Tools* panel to smooth the object, then in *Edit* mode create *Edge Loops* (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>)where you need to increase or decrease the radius, pull or push some vertices with the *Proportional Editing Mode* on, etc.

[image]